# Align table with text outside the table

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment

I would like to align the text in the first column of a table with the text outside the table. Here is a MWE:

```
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
{\bf Title} & Executive Manager &   \\
 & Email: xxx  &   Phone: xxx\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\noindent{\bf Description}

Here goes a paragraph...

\end{document}
```

I would like to align "Title" and "Description", which is not what happens now. Note that I would like to keep the outside text outside (i.e., not moving them into the table). Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `{@{}lll@{}`  also do not use `\bf` in latex documents

Comment: Beautiful! And thanks!! Two follow up questions: i) what is @{} doing? and ii) are you suggesting using \textbf?

Comment: `@{hello}` would add hello on every line, in general it replaces the default `\tabcolsep` padding space but here you want to replace with nothing so `@{}`. For the table heading yes,  `\bfseries` or `\textbf` . Presumably `Description` should be `\section*{Description}` or some such. As you have not said which document class you are using  `\bf` might not even be defined as unlike `\bfseries` the latex format does not define `\bf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A column specification of

```
{@{}lll@{}}
```

would remove the `\tabcolsep` padding space on either side of the table.